# Do retags count as an edit?

Tags: discussion, support

For the badge "strunk and white", do retags count as an edit?

Or is it necessary to change the letters in the title and the body?

Comment: They should, ideally. Tags effect the post far more than minor changes to title/body.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read somewhere on meta.SO that they don't, but I don't have the reference to hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) it says for Copy Editor (gold): "Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count" and at [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/445/171937) Jeff Atwood wrote "does not include edits to tags". Therefore: Quite probably they do not count.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will help :)